# Subset from data frame using vector with multiple

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a large data set composed of data (samples) from different experiments / conditions. I've made a data frame (Data_Design) in which I assigned the experiment.nr and condition to each sample.

```
> Data
              Samp1      Samp2      Samp3     Samp4     Samp5     Samp6
    GeneA        10         4          2         3          2        3       
    GeneB        3          335        12        12         2        23
    GeneC        5          6          2         3          243      3
    GeneD        122        132        132       21         22       34


> Data_Design
             Exps       Conds
Samp1        Exp1       CondA       
Samp2        Exp1       CondB    
Samp3        Exp2       CondC    
Samp4        Exp2       CondB    
Samp5        Exp3       CondB
Samp6        Exp3       CondC
```

Now I'd like to make a script that allows me to give several experiments / conditions of interest as an input (with variables) and that it will then extract the corresponding data. Like this:

```
> condition <- c("CondA","CondB")
> experiment <- c("Exp2","Exp3")

 >     Data.new <-  Data[, Data_Design$Conds == condition & Data_Design$Exps == experiment]
```

Result would then be:

```
> Data.new
              Samp4     Samp5
    GeneA     3          2       
    GeneB     12         2        
    GeneC     3          243      
    GeneD     21         22
```

In this case all options should be allowed, i.e. Exp2/CondA, Exp2/CondB, Exp3/CondA or Exp3/CondB.

However, up till now I did not get it to work. I guess I'm doing something wrong by assigning "condition" and "experiment", I should not use a vector?

Does anyone have good advice / an example?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this, but for now, this works. Note: In `Data_Design`, I put all the `Samp`s in a column called `Samp` instead of having them as rownames.

```
inputs <- expand.grid(experiment, condition, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(inputs) <- c('Exps', 'Conds')

inputs <- merge(inputs, Data_Design, by = c('Exps', 'Conds'), all.x = TRUE)

Data[, inputs$Samp[!is.na(inputs$Samp)]]
##      Samp4 Samp5
##GeneA     3     2
##GeneB    12     2
##GeneC     3   243
##GeneD    21    22
```